# call function while reading STDIN

Tags: perl, readline

I use Term::ReadLine::Gnu, 
I try to use event_loop, or event_hook, or callback_read_char attribute without success.

With event_loop, I try the sample in doc

```
$term->event_loop(sub {
    my $data = shift;
    $data->[1] = AE::cv();
    $data->[1]->recv();
    }, sub {
        my $fh = shift;
        my $data = [];
        $data->[0] = AE::io($fh, 0, sub { $data->[1]->send() });
        $data;
    });
```

and I have:

> Cannot do `event_loop' in Term::ReadLine::Gnu

event_hook works but not like I want...it's called too often during waiting not only when a char is printed.

I don't found how to use callback_read_char attribute and if meets my needs...

So, how to check input (to print only digit) and limit input length to 10 digits?
How can I do this? or do I have to use another module?

Comment: You should post your attempt here anyway, even if it doesn't work. That helps us help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I wanted:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::Screen::ReadLine;
use Data::Dumper;


main();

sub main
{
     $| =1 ;
     my $scr = new Term::Screen::ReadLine;
     $scr->clrscr();
     $scr->at(1,17)->puts('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
     $scr->at(2,21)->puts('*****************');
     $scr->at(4,0)->puts('- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
     $scr->at(5,0)->puts('  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: ...................');

     my $line=$scr->readline(
         ROW         => 5,
         COL         => 26,
         LEN         => 19,
         DISPLAYLEN  => 19,
         LINE        => '',
         ONLYVALID   => "[[:digit:]]+",
         CONVERT     => undef,
         PASSWORD    => undef,
         OVERWRITE   => 1,
     );
     $scr->at(6,0)->puts(' debug => :' . $line);
}
```